# Module Load: Unknown Module in Delphi, form is not showing when I run

Tags: module, load, unload

My program has been running fine, then suddenly I cannot see the form when I run the program.

At first it gave me an error:

```
Fatal Error: Cannot create output file "project1.exe"
```

Then, that disappeared, but now in my Events log, I have the following new error:

```
    Module Load: Unknown module no debug info base address process project.exe
    Module Unload: unknown module 3 process project.exe
    Module load unknown module4 no debug info base address process project.exe
```

And then there are plenty of thread exits.

Can someone please help?

I tried closing the program and restarted the computer to ensure the program isnt running elsewhere. I also debugged and the events appear when I create my first form.

Comment: Not enough information, please [edit] your question. Add a Delphi tag. Running from the IDE? What Delphi version? Info about your program (what 'modules' could this be about)? Third party components? Any relevant code?